# InvokeWorkflowActivity doesn't call workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, invoke

I'm trying to get one workflow to call another one. I tried using the invokeWorkflowActivity, I set the TargetWorkflow to the workflow that I want to get called. It's in another project so I added the project as a reference.

What else do I have to set up in order for this to work properly. I get no errors, the first workflow starts and then completes as expected because the call to start the workflow is asyncronous. The problem is that my second workflow doesn't seem like it's getting called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this sample..

http://blogs.msdn.com/sdanie/archive/2006/06/23/644366.aspx

this may help you